# How to add a new line into an tablix textbox on the basis of a field value into ssrs reporting

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am making an invoice into asp.net ssrs reporting and have a problem that after a product sales price i need to show discount but only if there is a discount on the item.I am giving you a sample data for it please check it i.e

```
Products                       Price
Item1                          1000

Item2                          1000
discount                       -100
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the visibility of the row with the discount based on the value.

```
    =iif(Fields!discount.value="", True, False)
```